# Tornado: Reset database before running all tests

Tags: python, tornado

I am using Python Tornado web server. When I write test, before all tests, I want to do something (such as prepare some data, reset database ...). How can I achieve this in Python or Tornado web server.

In some languages I can easily do this. Example: in Golang, there is a file named `main_test.go`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test folder, you create `__init__.py` and initialize everything here.

```
// __init__.py
reset_database()
run_migration()
seed_data()
```

Noted that, you should configure your project running test from root folder. For example, if your test inside `app/tests/api/sample_api.py`, your test should be run  from `app`. In this case, `__init__.py` will always run before running your `sample_api.py`. Here is the command line I usually run for running all tests inside project:

```
python -m unittest discover
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `unittest.TestCase` or `tornado.testing.*TestCase` (which actually are subclasses of `unittest.TestCase`), look at the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods. You can wrap everything you want just like

```
class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        load_data_to_db()

    def test_smth(self):
        self.assertIsInstance("setUp and tearDown are useful", str)

    def tearDown(self):
        cleanup_db()
```